# Training with sparse data

Tags: spacy, training-data

What are tips for training with Prodigy/Spacy when we have limited data (~500 samples)? The prodigy train-curve command says accuracy stayed the same in the last sample and that would indicate that collecting more annotations of the same type will not improve the model further. Yet, we are finding that the model is performing poorly when making predictions on unseen data.

We have tried training with the large spaCy model as a base model, and also without it. In both cases, we are seeing similar results. We have tried training with 80%/20% training/eval split and with 100% training set and both methods give subpar performance.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

NLP processing can be a bit dounting. As per what you are saying, there could be multiple factors that affect the performance of the model. The recommendations would also change based on what you are trying to achieve (group, predict, classify). As this is not a discussion forum, I will stick to the most common enhancements you can perform.

- Instead of `Houldout` train test separation (80%/20%), you can try implementing a `cross-validation`, that will separate the train/test data into sequential folds and all the data will be presented to the model, effectively creating one model per 'fold'. 10 folds is the recommended number by the literature.
- Try filtering out the most significant variables in the samples. A `chi²` calculation of the elements can be performed to calculate the most relevant features in the text entry. A [Tfidf](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) analysis and filter can be performed on top of that to only select the meaningfull features, excluding the most specific ones and generic ones.

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(encoding='utf-8',
                        ngram_range=ngram_range,
                        stop_words=stop_words,
                        lowercase=True,
                        max_df=max_df,
                        min_df=min_df,
                        max_features=max_features,
                        sublinear_tf=True)
                        
features_train = tfidf.fit_transform(X_train).toarray()
labels_train = y_train
print(features_train.shape)

features_test = tfidf.transform(X_test).toarray()
labels_test = y_test
print(features_test.shape)

from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
import numpy as np

for Product, category_id in sorted(category_codes.items()):
    features_chi2 = chi2(features_train, labels_train == category_id)
    indices = np.argsort(features_chi2[0])
    feature_names = np.array(tfidf.get_feature_names_out())[indices]
    unigrams = [v for v in feature_names if len(v.split(' ')) == 1]
    bigrams = [v for v in feature_names if len(v.split(' ')) == 2]
    print("# '{}' category:".format(Product))
    print("  . Most correlated unigrams:\n. {}".format('\n. '.join(unigrams[-5:])))
    print("  . Most correlated bigrams:\n. {}".format('\n. '.join(bigrams[-2:])))
    print("")
```

- Use randomSearch or other search algorithm to test multiple configurations and verify which configuration gives the best results. On that note, make sure to try different algorithms, such as Random Forest, SVM, Multinomial Naïve Bayes (make sure those are appropriated to solve yourt specific problem).
- Analyse the result of your AI. Check what it was able to do and where it failed. Try to build structures to help it where it's ocorring the most problems. This could be, for example, creating a specific model just to solve that one part of your problem the current model cannot.

Hope you find those tips usefull.

[Here](https://github.com/MasterExecuson/Data-Science-Analytics/blob/main/Data%20Analytics%20Hands%20On/03%20BBC_news%20(pr%C3%A1tica%20classifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20de%20textos).ipynb) are an example for NLP that might correlate to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The link for examples have some portguese words, but the code itself is in english. Just Ignore the comments, the code should be self explanatory.